# Lambda function applying length function to Dataframe gives different output

Tags: pandas, lambda, string-length

I have a Pandas Dataframe:
I wanted to calculate the length of each cell in row index=4.
I executed 2 commands and both give different answers. Can somebody explain what is happening here

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   first
1   3   4   5   6   7   8   second
2   6   7   8   9   10  11  third
3   first   second  third   fourth  fifth   sixth   fourth
4   column  column  column  column  column  column  fifth

First Command:
**df2.loc[4].apply(lambda x: len(x))**
Output:
a    6
b    6
c    6
d    6
e    6
f    6
g    5
Name: 4, dtype: int64

Second Command:
**df2.loc[4:].apply(lambda x: len(x))**
Output:
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    1
e    1
f    1
g    1
dtype: int64
```

- *New to Python*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your dataframe in a way that we can use it, see this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for help.

Comment: @joao: Thanks. I formatted it now. Looks better I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that difference is that calling `df2.loc[4]` produces a `Series` (with 7 elements), whereas calling `df2.loc[4:]` (`4:` is a *slice*) produces a `DataFrame` (with 1 row and 7 columns). Try using `print()` and `type()` on the two to see the difference.

- on a Series, `apply` invokes your function on the values of the Series, so you are indeed getting the lengths of the string values like you wanted.
- on a DataFrame, `apply` is invoking your function on each column, counting the number of elements (rows) in the column, and it's 1 because the `[4:]`slice defines a single row (try `[2:5]`, you'll get 3 instead of 1).

BTW, your lambda function is identical to the `len` function, so you can just write `.apply(len)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help It was clear to me now. Just 1 more thing, if I want to check the length of each cell of a dataframe iteratively. Then what is the solution @joao

Comment: `df2.applymap(len)`